# using Sms verification api in React native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to use Google Sms verification api in react native. At the beginning of the project, SMSReceiver initialized with SMSReceiverModule's context but when I receive sms, SMSReceiver will be initialized again with no context, and if I remove empty constructor in SMSReceiver my project will crashing. how can I avoid initializing SMSReceiver for the seccound time

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private ReactApplicationContext mContext;
    private static final String EVENT = "SMS_RECEIVED";

    public SMSReceiver() {
    }

    public SMSReceiver(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                    processMessage(message);
                    break;
                case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:                    
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void processMessage(String message) {

        if (mContext == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (!mContext.hasActiveCatalystInstance()) {
           !hasActiveCatalystInstance", message);
            return;
        }

        WritableNativeMap map = new WritableNativeMap();

        map.putString("message", message);
        mContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(EVENT, map);
    }
}
```

and my react module is look like this:

```
public class SMSReceiverModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventListener {
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
    private boolean isReceiverRegistered = false;
    private Context _context;

    public SMSReceiverModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        this._context = context;
        mBroadcastReceiver = new SMSReceiver(context);
        getReactApplicationContext().addLifecycleEventListener(this);

        SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(context);

        Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();

        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Successfully started retriever, expect broadcast intent
                // ...
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Failed to start retriever, inspect Exception for more details
                // ...
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerReceiver() {
        String filter = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) ?
                Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION :
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

        if (getCurrentActivity() != null) {
            getCurrentActivity().registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(filter));
            isReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    private void unregisterReceiver() {
        if (isReceiverRegistered && getCurrentActivity() != null) {
            getCurrentActivity().unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
            isReceiverRegistered = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "SMSReceiverModule";
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostResume() {
        registerReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostPause() {
        unregisterReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onHostDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use Singleton method for `SMSReceiver ` class or check context then initialize it. Please use `Event emitter` for sending your events through your react native app. [See the documentations](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android).

Comment: I used DeviceEventEmitter in my native modules, that is not the point, because this code works on regular sms reciever but when I change it to google sms verification api it dosent work anymore, It must be simple that i cant see it